# EADDRNOTAVAIL even after using IP_FREEBIND?

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-kernel, ip

I was under the impression that under Linux you could bind to a non-local address as long as you set the `IP_FREEBIND` socket option, but that's not the behavior I'm seeing:

```
$ sudo strace -e 'trace=%network' ...
...
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP)  = 5
setsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NO_CHECK, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(5, SOL_IP, IP_HDRINCL, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(5, SOL_IP, IP_FREEBIND, [1], 4) = 0
bind(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(abcd), sin_addr=inet_addr("w.x.y.z")}, 16) = -1 EADDRNOTAVAIL (Cannot assign requested address)
...
```

I also set the `ip_nonlocal_bind` setting, just to be certain, and I get the same results.

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1
```

Comment: If there is a specific IP you want to receive, can't you add that address to the interface and open it as a local address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that it is not possible to bind a raw IP socket to a non-local, non-broadcast and non-multicast address, regardless of `IP_FREEBIND`. Since I see `inet_addr("w.x.y.z")` in your `strace` output, I assume that this is exactly what you're trying to do and `w.x.y.z` is a non-local unicast address, thus your `bind` syscall fails.

This seems in accordance with [`man 7 raw`](https://manned.org/raw.7):

> A raw socket **can be bound to a specific local  address**  using  the
> `bind(2)`  call.   If it isn't bound, all packets with the specified
> IP protocol are received.  In addition, a raw socket can be  bound
> to a specific network device using `SO_BINDTODEVICE`; see `socket(7)`.

Indeed, looking at the kernel source code, in `raw_bind()` we can see [the following check](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.7/source/net/ipv4/raw.c#L735):

```c
    ret = -EADDRNOTAVAIL;
    if (addr->sin_addr.s_addr && chk_addr_ret != RTN_LOCAL &&
        chk_addr_ret != RTN_MULTICAST && chk_addr_ret != RTN_BROADCAST)
        goto out;
```

Also, note that `.sin_port` must be `0`. The `.sin_port` field for raw sockets is used to select a sending/receiving IP protocol (not a port, since we are at level 3 and ports do not exist). As the manual states, from Linux 2.2 onwards you cannot select a sending protocol through `.sin_port` anymore, the sending protocol is the one set when creating the socket.